# Load content in modal onSubmit if content loaded with .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, joomla2.5

We are currently loading content into an `iframe` on a Twitter Bootstrap modal box. However, styles are not carried through because we load the content with Joomla's content-only suffix: `?tmpl=component`.

```
<?php echo '…
$("a[data-toggle=\'"+$modalText+"\']").on(\'click\', function (e) {
    // Call the modal manually
    var url = $(this).attr(\'href\');
    $modal.find(".modal-body-content").html(\'<iframe frameborder="0" width="100%" height="700" allowtransparency="true" src="\' + url + \'"></iframe >\');
    $modal.modal("show");
});
…';?>
```

The reason for this is that the content contains a form & submit button. Is there a way to keep content inside the modal and submit inside the modal if we load the content via jQuery's `.load()` function?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "submit inside the modal", you should prevent the default form submit (which would trigger a full page load), and send an ajax request instead.

You can do this by hand, or use the jQuery form plugin (you can find it [here](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)) and call `.ajaxForm()` :

```
//to be called once, when the form is present in the DOM
$('#myForm').ajaxForm({
    success: function(data){
       //code to execute when submit successfully returned from server
       //the "data" variable contains whatever the answer is : html, json ...
    }
    //you define here any option of the "$.ajax()" function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also edit the component.php in your template directory to include a CSS file. That way you can avoid having to code anything in jQuery ;)